# Echoing Characters and removing special characters, numbers

Tags: bash

I'm looking at a way to echo a line showing only me the characters for example

My line would be `Alex.Chin1`

and I want to echo `Alex Chin` (prefer to keep the space in between the name)

How would I do this in Bash

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
echo "Alex.Chin1" | tr '.' ' ' | tr -d [:digit:]
```

- replaces `.` with a space
- removes all digits